# Skipping data binding triggered events in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, logging, data-binding

I'm trying to log all user interactions (button clicks, list selection changes, etc.) in a legacy WPF application. I did this by subclassing all windows control classes (Button, TextBox, ComboBox, etc.) and overwritten certain functions (e.g. OnClick() in the Button subclass) to log when these events happen.

The problem is almost all controls in the application use data binding and when a page is loaded it kicks in for all these elements and event handlers are automatically called. I only want to log these when the user changes these controls.

Is there an elegant way to skip the events that are triggered by data binding when I'm logging?

Comment: Like which events are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event handler, construct a `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` which contains all the stack frames from the event handler all the way down to Main method of the application.

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(trace.ToString());
```

Take `SelectionChanged` event for an example, if the event is triggered by data binding, there should be some frames looks like

> at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
> ...
>
> at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.set_ItemsSource(IEnumerable value)